# Microsoft.Graph.Message to MsgKit.Email images missing when object saved as .msg file

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to convert Microsoft.Graph.Message to MsgKit.Email object and save the object as `.msg` file. I am able to read fileattachment and save but images are not getting saved in my .msg file.
Please guide and help me..

```
var email = new Email(new Sender(message.Sender.EmailAddress.Address, message.Sender.EmailAddress.Name), message.Subject);

email.SentOn = DateTimeOffset.Parse(message.SentDateTime.ToString()).DateTime;
email.ReceivedOn = DateTimeOffset.Parse(message.ReceivedDateTime.ToString()).DateTime;
email.InternetMessageId = message.InternetMessageId;

//Importance
switch (message.Importance)
{
    case Importance.Low:
        email.Importance = MessageImportance.IMPORTANCE_LOW;
        break;
    case Importance.Normal:
        email.Importance = MessageImportance.IMPORTANCE_NORMAL;
        break;
    case Importance.High:
        email.Importance = MessageImportance.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        break;
}

//To
foreach (var to in message.ToRecipients)
{
    email.Recipients.AddTo(to.EmailAddress.Address, to.EmailAddress.Name);
}

//Cc
foreach (var cc in message.CcRecipients)
{
    email.Recipients.AddCc(cc.EmailAddress.Address, cc.EmailAddress.Name);
}

//Bcc
foreach (var bcc in message.BccRecipients)
{
    email.Recipients.AddBcc(bcc.EmailAddress.Address, bcc.EmailAddress.Name);
}


switch (message.Body.ContentType)
{
    case BodyType.Text:
        email.BodyText = message.Body.Content;
        break;
    case BodyType.Html:
        email.BodyHtml = message.Body.Content;
        break;
    default:
        email.BodyText = message.Body.Content;
        break;
}

if (message.HasAttachments == true)
{
    foreach (dynamic attachmentFile in message.Attachments)
    {
        if (attachmentFile.ODataType.ToLower() == ("#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment").ToLower())
        {
            var fileStream = new MemoryStream(attachmentFile.ContentBytes);
            email.Attachments.Add(fileStream, attachmentFile.Name, -1, attachmentFile.IsInline, attachmentFile.Id);
        }
        else if (attachmentFile.ODataType.ToLower() == ("#microsoft.graph.itemAttachment").ToLower())
        {
            email.Attachments.Add(attachmentFile.Name, -1, attachmentFile.IsInline, attachmentFile.Id);
        }
    }
}
email.Save(@"E:\EmailMessages\email.msg");
```

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: When i have .eml file as an attachment in my email message the code recognize that as an ItemAttachment so when i try to add that as an attachment it gives me an error that "Could not find file 'C:\Users\dineshkumarl\MimeKitGraphAPI\bin\Debug\EmlWithAttachment.eml'.". I Please guide me as how can we save ItemAttachment in attachments.

Comment: did you come to a solution? If so, can you share it?

Comment: I was trying to save email as msg file. Steps which I followed

Answer (score 0):

You need to request the attachments in a separate request.

```cs
if (message.HasAttachments == true)
{
    // Get attachment information.
    var attachmentsInfo = await graphClient.Me.Messages[message.Id]
                                                           .Attachments
                                                           .Request()
                                                           .Select("id")
                                                           .GetAsync();


    foreach (var attachmentFileInfo in attachmentsInfo)
    {
        if (attachmentFileInfo.ODataType.ToLower() == ("#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment").ToLower())
        {
            // Get the attachment bytes
            var attachment = await graphClient.Me.Messages[message.Id]
                                                          .Attachments[attachmentFileInfo.Id]
                                                          .Request()
                                                          .GetAsync();
            var fileStream = new MemoryStream(attachment.ContentBytes);
            email.Attachments.Add(fileStream, attachment.Name, -1, attachment.IsInline, attachmment.Id);
        }
        else if (attachment.ODataType.ToLower() == ("#microsoft.graph.itemAttachment").ToLower())
        {

            email.Attachments.Add(attachment.Name, -1, attachment.IsInline, attachment.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Apologize i am doing the attachment retrival part separately the code snippet which i shared will take Graph.Message object as parameter and using that it builds Email object which i am using to save the email as .msg file. The Graph.Message contains all the attachments a email has.